# how can C++ macro use for two string literal

Tags: c++, visual-c++, text, literals

I used these macros before:

```
#define TEXT_A   _T("a")
#define TEXT_B   _T("b")

std::wstring text = TEXT_A TEXT_B;      // then text = "ab"
```

now how can i do this:

```
#define TEXT_A   "a"
#define TEXT_B   "b"
std::wstring text = _T(TEXT_A TEXT_B);     // i need text be "ab" but failed.  and that error is wchar_t cannot connect with char.
```

I'm looking for a macro to do that.

Comment: i need marco because i have a lot of const string. and i don't want a typing wrong.

Comment: i try boost::preproceesor, but it needs my string marco with ( ). it will treat as a seque. then use BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH to connect. but it complicated.

Comment: Note that somewhat ironically, `_T(TEXT_A TEXT_B);` would work in GCC because it expands to `L"a" "b"` (assuming that `_T()` is targeting wide characters) and GCC properly implements string literal concatenation when only one of literals has an `L` prefix. However, MSVC doesn't, so it falls over with `error C2308`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
std::wstring text = _T(TEXT_A) _T(TEXT_B);
```

Even a better solution: [stop using `wstring`](http://utf8everywhere.org/).

Comment: thanks. but what if i have a marco #define TEXTAB  TEXT_A TEXTB.\n        then _T(TEXTAB)  will ocu a error. btw, how can i input new line in comment. "enter" not work.

Comment: @tnntnn: Then you cannot do it in compile time. Mark is right, stop using macros... And use multi line comments `\* ... *\` to do multi line comments!

Comment: @ybungalobill: oh. thank you for tip, I hadn't noticed comment. any solution without marco to deal the same string literal

Comment: @tnntnn: As I said, in the case you describe, you will have to do the conversion at runtime with something like `MultiByteToWideChar` function.

Comment: @tnntnn: You only use `_T` around "" string literals. `TEXTAB` is not a string literal so you should not write `_T(TEXTAB)`.